# Reading message from gear2

Tags: sms, tizen-wearable-sdk

I am new in tizen. I want to build a app that read the sms from Gear and show all sms title in a list. Is it possible to retrieve sms from Gear2? If possible what will be the procedure.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

The only way would be to get SMS via SAP protocole. You can read about it in SDK help (API ref/DeviceAPI/Comm/SAP)
and here with example:
http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000160